# Setting a struct equal to a value

Tags: c, struct

Let's say I have a `struct` with a field `x` that is also a `struct` (not a pointer to a `struct`).

If I say `object.x = 0`, what is actually happening under the hood?

Comment: Can you post some compileable sample code? `object.x = 0` won't compile if `x` is a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work. You'II get an error of incompatible types, like this:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct X’ from type ‘int’.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it won't compile but i can't check at the moment but

```
object.x = {0};
```

Should initialize all fields to 0.

UPDATE

previous doesn't compile because this can be only done at declaration, but following is ok

```
object.X = (struct struct1) {0};
```

which is equivalent to

```
{
  struct struct1 temp = {0};
  object.X = temp;
}
```

Comment: that will not compile when x is a struct

Comment: You can with C99 compound literals. `object.x = ((struct X){0});`

Answer (score 2):

You'll get a compile error.

```
error: incompatible types in assignment
```

You can't assign an `int` to a struct variable.